# Passing args in web2py

Tags: web2py

My table is:

```
db.define_table('test', Field('name'), Field('pics', 'upload'))
```

The actions:

```
def index():
    rows = db().select(db.test.ALL, limitby=(0, 5), orderby='<random>')
    return locals()

def other():
    image = db.test(request.args(0,cast=int)) or redirect(URL('index'))
    return locals()
```

The index view:

```
{{import random

k=random.randint(0, 4)}}
<div>
<img width="500px"
     src="{{=URL('download', args=rows[k].pics)}}" />
</div>

{{block left_sidebar}}
{{for row in rows:}}
{{=LI(A(row.name, _href=URL('other', args=row.id)))}}
{{pass}}
{{end}}
```

Now I have 5 random `name` displayed and 1 random `pics`, the 1 `pics` has the same id as one of the five `name`.

What I want to achieve is this: If the `name` that matches the one `pics`  is clicked I want to display something in `other`, *right answer* and if any of the other 4 `name` is clicked I want to display something else in `other`, *wrong answer*.

I'd appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to store the pic id in the session:

```
import random

def index():
    rows = db().select(db.test.ALL, limitby=(0, 5), orderby='<random>')
    pic_row = rows[random.randint(0, 4)]
    session.pic_id = pic_row.id
    return dict(rows=rows, pic_row=pic_row)
```

In the view:

```
<div>
<img width="500px"
     src="{{=URL('download', args=pic_row.pics)}}" />
</div>
```

Finally, check for a match in `other()`:

```
def other():
    image = db.test(request.args(0,cast=int)) or redirect(URL('index'))
    correct = image.id == session.pic_id
    del session.pic_id # to prevent multiple attempts
    return dict(image=image, correct=correct)
```

It is better to store the pic id in the session rather than embed it in a URL in the page so the user can't hack the URL or figure out the right answer by inspecting the HTML. Also, note that `session.pic_id` is deleted after a single check so the user cannot make multiple guesses by hitting the back button.

Finally, note that it is best to keep as much logic as possible in the controller rather than in the view. So, rather than selecting a random record in the view, do it in the controller and then just send the selected record to the view.

Comment: thanks so much! Thank you for the answer and the explanation. This really helps me understand how this works and why. I appreciate this very much!